# React-Native Camera did not open in android

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-camera

I'm using **expo** for React-Native. React-Native camera works fine in **iPhone** but in **android** device it's not opening. In Android device it open when i open it with expo but when i generate **apk** file it's not opening. I checked the log it says camera don't has the permission. Please help me to solve this here is an example of my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Camera, Permissions } from 'expo';

export default class CameraExample extends React.Component {
  state = {
    hasCameraPermission: null,
    type: Camera.Constants.Type.back,
  };



async componentWillMount() {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    this.setState({ hasCameraPermission: status === 'granted' });
  }

  render() {
    const { hasCameraPermission } = this.state;
    if (hasCameraPermission === null) {
      return <View />;
    } else if (hasCameraPermission === false) {
      return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Camera style={{ flex: 1 }} type={this.state.type}>
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                flexDirection: 'row',
              }}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                  flex: 0.1,
                  alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                }}
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setState({
                    type: this.state.type === Camera.Constants.Type.back
                      ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
                      : Camera.Constants.Type.back,
                  });
                }}>
                <Text
                  style={{ fontSize: 18, marginBottom: 10, color: 'white' }}>
                  {' '}Flip{' '}
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </Camera>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do you include camera permissions in `app.json`?

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/configuration.html#permissions

It should look something along the lines of:

```
{
  "expo": {
    ...
    "android": {
      "permissions": ["CAMERA"]
    }
  }
}
```